Angular 18 with CSP blocking styles set in component sass file
All, I have a simple "hello world" site to debug CSP.   I have it working fine for everything but styles that are placed in a component scss file.  What am I missing?
my index.html file:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test with CSP</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-123456789' 'strict-dynamic'; style-src 'nonce-123456789' 'self'; img-src  'self' data:; font-src 'self'; form-action 'self';">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  Body - 2
  <app-root ngCspNonce="nonce-123456789"></app-root> 
</body>

My app.module:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ], 
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    provideClientHydration(),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }

My home.component.ts
<p class="text-blue-500">{{hello}}</p> 
<p class="specialText">Special Text</p> 

And the home.component.scss
.specialText {
   color: red;
}

I am using PrimeNg/PrimeFlex.  Those classes all work fine.  WHat's getting blocked is the .specialText in the component.
And this is just a test.  The nonce values are strictly to prove out.  Once I have a working example, I'll put real nonce values in, etc.
Thanks,
Nick

When using the ngCspNonce attribute, you need to omit the nonce- prefix:
<app-root ngCspNonce="123456789"></app-root> 

See https://angular.dev/best-practices/security#content-security-policy

Thanks!   I couldn't tell you how many times I looked at that Angular.Dev page.  It's always the little things.
